# xsl:sort by variable

Tags: xslt

I've been looking at threads about sorting XML using `<xsl:sort>` and variables, and still can't get my sorting to work.  Here's some XML structure for context:

```
<records>
  <record>
    <contributors>
      <authors>
        <author>Author 1</author>
        <author>Author 2</author>
      </authors>
    </contributors>
    <titles>
      <title>I'm a Title!</title>
      <secondary-title></secondary-title>
    </titles>
    <dates>
      <year>1901</year>
    </dates>
  </record>
  <record>...</record>
  <record>...</record>
</records>
```

And here's the relevant XSL:

```
<xsl:variable name="sortby" 
              select="contributors/authors/author[1]" as="element()*"/>
<xsl:for-each select="//record">
  <xsl:sort select="$sortby" order="ascending"/>
  [a bunch of HTML to render the records as a bibliography]
</xsl:for-each>
```

If I copy the string in the variable's "select" attributes and paste it into sort, like this:

```
<xsl:sort select="contributors/authors/author[1]" order="ascending">
```

then it works.  With the variable, it doesn't. I tried it both with and without `as="element()*"` -- Help?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an answer explaining that there isn't a general XSLT solution to this problem, but provides a flexible solution that solves your specific problem and a large class of similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

**It is not possible in general to perform dynamic evaluation of XPath expressions -- neither in XSLT/Xpath 1.0 or in XSLT/Xpath 2.0**.

This said, one can always implement sorting guided by variables, if there are some limitations on their contents.

**Here is an example that solves your specific problem and a class of similar problems:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pSortName" select="'authors'"/>
 <xsl:param name="pSortPosition" select="1"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="records">
  <records>
   <xsl:apply-templates>
     <xsl:sort select=
     ".//*[name()=$pSortName]/*
             [position()=$pSortPosition]"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
  </records>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on this XML document**:

```
<records>
    <record>
        <contributors>
            <authors>
                <author>X.Y.Z</author>
                <author>A.B.C</author>
            </authors>
        </contributors>
        <titles>
            <title>Title B</title>
            <secondary-title>Title AB</secondary-title>
        </titles>
        <dates>
            <year>1901</year>
        </dates>
    </record>
    <record>
        <contributors>
            <authors>
                <author>T.U.V</author>
                <author>D.E.F</author>
            </authors>
        </contributors>
        <titles>
            <title>Title A</title>
            <secondary-title>Title BA</secondary-title>
        </titles>
        <dates>
            <year>2001</year>
        </dates>
    </record>
</records>
```

**the wanted, correct result (the records sorted by first author) is produced**:

```
<records>
   <record>
      <contributors>
         <authors>
            <author>T.U.V</author>
            <author>D.E.F</author>
         </authors>
      </contributors>
      <titles>
         <title>Title A</title>
         <secondary-title>Title BA</secondary-title>
      </titles>
      <dates>
         <year>2001</year>
      </dates>
   </record>
   <record>
      <contributors>
         <authors>
            <author>X.Y.Z</author>
            <author>A.B.C</author>
         </authors>
      </contributors>
      <titles>
         <title>Title B</title>
         <secondary-title>Title AB</secondary-title>
      </titles>
      <dates>
         <year>1901</year>
      </dates>
   </record>
</records>
```

**If we change the parameters to**:

```
 <xsl:param name="pSortName" select="'authors'"/>
 <xsl:param name="pSortPosition" select="2"/>
```

**then the transformation sorts using as sort-key the second `author`**.

**If we change the parameters to**:

```
 <xsl:param name="pSortName" select="'titles'"/>
 <xsl:param name="pSortPosition" select="1"/>
```

**then the transformation sorts using as sort-key the `titles/title` element**.

**If we change the parameters to**:

```
 <xsl:param name="pSortName" select="'titles'"/>
 <xsl:param name="pSortPosition" select="2"/>
```

**then the transformation sorts using as sort-key the `titles/secondary-title` element**.

**Do note**: Here we assume that there will be a unique descendent of any element being sorted, whose name is equal to the value specified in `pSortName`. We also assume that this element has children elements and `pSortPosition` specifies the position of the child to be used as a sort key.

Answer (score 1):

Two other solutions that haven't been mentioned:

(a) Many processors have an extension, called something like dyn:evaluate() that evaluates an XPath expression supplied in the form of a character string

(b) In some environments it's feasible to modify the stylesheet (using an XSLT transformation of course) before executing it. This allows you to insert whatever XPath expression you need. In XSLT 2.0 you can write the sort key as `select="my:sort(.)"`, and then define my:sort() in a separate xsl:included stylesheet module.

Another related option which I've seen is to use an external entity: select="&sortkey;", where the entity reference can be redirected programmatically to a different XPath expression using an EntityResolver registered with the XML parser.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a variable in the `select=` portion of an `xsl:sort` element. The [XSLT specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#sorting) states:

> `xsl:sort` has a `select` attribute whose value is an expression. For each node to be processed, the expression is evaluated with that node as the current node and with the complete list of nodes being processed in unsorted order as the current node list.

The expression is evaluated only *once*, not twice as you seem to expect. Your expression `$sortby` is evaluated once to result in something that is the same every time (the actual value depends on what was the current node at the time the `xsl:variable` assignment ran). Therefore, the sort does not change the order of the selected elements.

You must use a specific expression as the sort criteria, as you have discovered.

Comment: Thanks, Greg. Forgot to mention that I've also tried to use the variable without the select attribute, inserting the path between the opening and closing tags of the variable.  That didn't work either. Do you have a suggestion as to what I might try next?

Comment: You can't sort based on a variable expression (and you haven't described why you believe you need to). To sort by a particular key value, use the *actual* expression in the `select` attribute, as you describe at the bottom of your question.

Comment: Sorry.  I need to, because eventually I want to sort based on a variety of variables (by author name, by year, by publisher). I want to present the end user with a bibliography that can then be sorted by clicking on hyperlinks or buttons. I tried JavaScript but get lost in it reliably. Thought I'd try doing it with an XSL variable or parameter.

Comment: More accurately, you CAN use a variable in the select attribute of xsl:sort, but doing so means that every item in the input sequence will have exactly the same character string as its sort key, so it's not very useful.